# How to test redux-saga delay

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

### Problem

In `redux-saga`, I am using `yield delay(1000);`.
During my unit test, I do `expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(delay(1000));`.

I expect the test to pass.

This is my `sagas.js`:

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';

export function* incrementAsync() {
  yield delay(1000);
}
```

This is my `sagas.test.js`

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { incrementAsync } from '../sagas';

describe('incrementAsync Saga test', () => {
  it('should incrementAsync', () => {
    const generator = incrementAsync();
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(delay(1000));
  });
});
```

● incrementAsync Saga test › should incrementAsync

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  {"@@redux-saga/CANCEL_PROMISE": [Function anonymous]}
Received:
  {"@@redux-saga/CANCEL_PROMISE": [Function anonymous]}

Difference:

Compared values have no visual difference.
```

### question

How can I test **redux-saga** **delay** ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check `delay` saga effect [code](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/io.js#L227) you can see that it is a bound function:

```
export const delay = call.bind(null, delayUtil)
```

so if you import `delay` in two different modules it will be two different functions that **have no visual difference**.

You can check this in the codesandbox example (see test tab):

[image: Edit redux-saga delay test]

```
const testFunction = () => {};

describe("example bound functions equality test", () => {
  it("Two bound functions are not equal", () => {
    expect(testFunction.bind(this))
      .not.toEqual(testFunction.bind(this));
  });
});
```

Result is:
[image]

To test your saga you should mock your `delay` effect (if you are using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules));

```
import { delay } from "redux-saga";
import { incrementAsync } from "../sagas";

jest.mock("redux-saga");

describe("incrementAsync Saga test", () => {
  it("should incrementAsync", () => {
    const generator = incrementAsync();
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(delay(1000));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

A good way to test Redux Saga calls is by using the `call` effect. In this case, you can slightly refactor your saga as follows:

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* incrementAsync() {
  yield call(delay, 1000);
}
```

You would then test this like so:

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

describe('incrementAsync', () => {
  it('should incrementAsync()', () => {
    const generator = incrementAsync();

    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(delay, 1000));
  });
});
```

This works because the result of the yield to `call` is a simple object, describing a call to the `delay` function. No need for any mocks :)

There is also of course the great `redux-saga-test-plan` helper library. Using that, your test would become the following:

```
import { testSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

describe('incrementAsync', () => {
  it('should incrementAsync()', () => {
    testSaga(incrementAsync)
      .next()
      .call(delay, 1000)
      .next()
      .isDone();
  });
});
```

Comment: If I do that in expectSaga(...) call stack, it gives me the following error: `instead of writing 'yield call(delay, 600)' where delay is an effect from 'redux-saga/effects' you should write 'yield delay(600)'`

Comment: Interesting, is that using the latest version? It might have changed since I gave this answer.

Comment: Yes @FelaMaslen that's for the last version, I just faced this problem on project.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone hits the below issue when using the `redux-saga-test-plan` package.

> instead of writing 'yield call(delay, 600)' where delay is an effect from 'redux-saga/effects' you should write 'yield delay(600)'

You should do this:

`saga.ts`:

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* incrementAsync() {
  yield delay(1000);
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { testSaga } from "redux-saga-test-plan"
import { incrementAsync } from "./saga"

describe('incrementAsync', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    testSaga(incrementAsync).next().delay(1000).next().isDone();
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/49263089/saga.test.ts
  incrementAsync
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 saga.ts  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.208 s
```

package versions:

```json
"redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.1",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
```